# is wrong to add my code in wp admin page wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I must to add new options and functions in post pages in admin panel. I call a new function in edit-form-advanced.php and edded this function in template.php file. The question is this wrong? Becouse my function is in one file with functions on wordpress. Or maybe must be in other file? but where i must call it? 
For wp-content part i know and i make a child theme of parent theme, but i do not know what to do when i must add code in wp-admin part.
example:
edit-form-advanced.php

```
do_custom_boxes( null, $post );
```

and in template.php

```
function do_custom_boxes( $screen, $object ) {
    global $wpdb;
     $appTable = $wpdb->prefix . "post_panel";
    $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $appTable WHERE post_id = ".$_GET['post']." ", $screen);
    $applications = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    ......
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes, it's wrong to do so. Whenever you update your WordPress you'll loose all your changes.

WordPress allows you to hook into its code, modify its behavior and many things.

Please read about [actions](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/actions/) and [filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/).

Basically, **Actions** allow you to **fire a function when something happens** in WordPress.

For example:

```
<?php
function do_something_when_admin_pages_init() {
    // Do something here
}
add_action('admin_init', 'do_something_when_admin_pages_init')
```

**Filters** allow you to modify data/output of another function. It's like it let you step in the middle, do something with the data and then continue.

Example from the WordPress page:

```
<?php
function wporg_filter_title($title) {
    return 'The ' . $title . ' was filtered';
}
add_filter('the_title', 'wporg_filter_title');
```

This modifies the title before it's printed.

So with those two ways of 'hooking' into the WordPress code, you can write your code in your theme's functions.php file, or write a Plugin (it's up to you).